# Downloading file from FTP with PHP

Tags: php, html, ftp

I'm pretty new to FTP, and I'm trying to download a file to view it when it is saved local. But the first part is not going really smoothly...

I used this code:

```
        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

        // login with username and password
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass);

        // define some variables
        $local_file = 'server.txt';
        $server_file = '/httpdocs/project/server/server.txt';

        // try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
        if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
            echo "Successfully written to this";
        } else {
            echo "There was a problem";
        }
```

But it isn't working, I don't know what the problem is. Do I have to set some permissions or stuff? I couldn't figure out what was wrong so this is kind of my last hope.

Where are my mistakes? Is it because of this code or is it something else?

Comment: why FTP_BINARY for .txt file(FTP_ASCII is an option too)?also can u use     $conn_id= ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect");

Comment: 2 possible problems: 1) it's not connecting or 2) the filename/path is not correct

Comment: I made sure it's connected, the second problem might be possible. Where does $server_file come from? from my document root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where are my mistakes? Is it because of this code or is it something else?

Your code is completly fine. I know because I tested it.

2 possible problems:

1. it's not connecting
2. the filename/path (`$server_file`) is not correct

> I made sure it's connected, the second problem might be possible. Where does $server_file come from? from my document root?

`$server_file` is the file you want to download from your server. Only you know the correct path.
Because we cannot tell which directory does the user have access to.

Please check that `/httpdocs/project/server/server.txt` is the correct path of your file.

Comment: Well, /httpdocs/ is my document root, does it have to be inside of the path or not? Or should the complete path be something like http:// www.example.com/project/server/server.txt

Comment: @user2177152 use FileZilla and connect, if you dont see `httpdocs` directory in your root folder then you have the wrong path. `/` is telling the server to look in the root directory.

Comment: It is in my root folder... @meda

Comment: @user2177152 try like this `httpdocs/project/server/server.txt`